# Getting an input box entry to sit after specific text in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an input box that gets a customer to enter their business name when they open the sheet.

The sheet is set up to be saved as a CSV file to be imported straight into our system.

This code is as below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim myValue As Variant

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="myPassword"

    myValue = InputBox("Please enter your Business Name:")
    Range("C2").Value = myValue

    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="myPassword"

End Sub
```

I would like the `myValue` to be entered into one of the column headings but it needs to be started with group:

e.g. if a customer inserts Stackoverflow as the business - I would like the data to go into cell C2 as `group:Stackoverflow`

Has anyone got any ideas on how I could do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you just need to join `group:` and `myValue`:

```
Range("C2").Value = "group:" & myValue
```